# UITableViewCell & getting bounds/frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `UITableView cell`, in a `UITableView`.  When i am trying to add new value from search bar list selected that time that value i am adding into table and same time displying the popover on that newly added cell but some time its working perfect but no of times it display anywhere i am using cell.frame my code is bellow for the same i am attach the expected result screen short also please any one know then help me [image: I expect like this image every time]

```
- (void)loadPopOver:(id)idDataObj {
    NSDictionary *dictDataObj = (NSDictionary*)idDataObj;
    //add the popOverControl

    OrdersDetailPopViewController *orderDetailPopVC = [[OrdersDetailPopViewController alloc] init];
    orderDetailPopVC.idParentDelegate = self;

    CGSize sizeObj = [orderDetailPopVC initView:5 totalTextArea:0 dataForTableViews:[dictDataObj valueForKey:TAG_DATASOURCE] titles:[dictDataObj valueForKey:TAG_TITLES]];

    if (sizeObj.height == 0 && sizeObj.width == 0) {
        NSLog(@"API Error : Incomplete data sent.");
        return;
    }

    //Point from where to show the popOverControl
    CGRect cgRect;
    if (indexPathLastSelected.section == -1 ) {

        if([_isFromSearchBar isEqualToString:@"FROM_SEARCH_BAR"])
        {
             UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewLeft cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
             cgRect = cell.frame;
             //cgRect.origin.y = 190;
             cgRect.origin.y = 25;
             //cgRect.origin.x =270;
        }
        else if([_isFromRightTable isEqualToString:@"FROM_RIGHT_TABLE"])
        {
             UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewLeft cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
             cgRect = cell.frame;
        }
    }
    else {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewLeft cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathLastSelected];
        cgRect = cell.frame;
    }
    popOverFormInput = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:orderDetailPopVC];
    popOverFormInput.contentViewController = orderDetailPopVC;
    [popOverFormInput setPopoverContentSize:sizeObj];
    popOverFormInput.delegate = self;
    if (self.view.window != nil)
    [popOverFormInput presentPopoverFromRect:cgRect inView:tableViewLeft permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Dude that is ONE LONG sentence! I don't understand the problem that you're facing :\

Comment: Hi Pavan The problem is that when i add new item form search bar to tableview that time i showing one popover but it not work properly there is one contion if([_isFromSearchBar isEqualToString:@"FROM_SEARCH_BAR"]) in this conditon i am not able to show the popover as per screen shot is attached some time it work but no of time no work

Comment: yes, I can see now what you are talking about, but now the question is what it is that you're trying to accomplish, because the chances are that you're not doing it the right way; I can see some funky code in your code block. Tell us what it is you're trying to achieve overall so that we can tell you the proper way so that you can achieve the overall goal.

Comment: I am trying to achieve when i add the new item from search bar that time i want to show popover like screen short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of calling method i just put the delay 
and i fixed the issue
[self performSelector:@selector(showPopOver) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.20];

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of funky code in your project which I highly suggest you revise. For now though, I suggest going for simplicity and using a method like this

```
//Get the cell's frame that you're interested in
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewLeft cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedindexPath]

//and then use that cell's frame to position your popover over it.
[popOverFormInput presentPopoverFromRect:[cell frame] inView:cell.contentView 
             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to popup using the CGRect, It might not the superView's frame Or else you are somewhere misusing of the frame Value.

Better get(Note) the NSIndePath of the tableView. Later can use it to popup from it >

For Ex:

```
    - (void)loadPopOver:(id)idDataObj {
     NSIndexPath *selectedindexPath;
    .
    .
    .
    if([_isFromSearchBar isEqualToString:@"FROM_SEARCH_BAR"])
      selectedindexPath = // [tableViewLeft cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
    .
    .
    .
    // Try this to pop your View 
    [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:[tableViewLeft rectForRowAtIndexPath:selectedindexPath] inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```